# Some RelativeLayout.LayoutParams doesn't work

Tags: android, layoutparams

Background: I'm making an application that can creates timed based alarms, location based or both and in the activity that creates the alarm I have checkbox for each- timepicker and map and you uncheck it if you don't want one of these features in your alarm. Here's a picture of this activity-http://prntscr.com/dr1s74 .

If you uncheck the map checkbox it removes the fragment and sets layout params of the radioGroup to below the title (because the map is gone now), center it and to add margin.

While addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id) works, both setMargins(left, top, right, bottom) and addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) doesn't work and because of that the radioGroup is off center and without the correct space below the title.

XML Activity:

Description of the possible problem: The only reason I can think it happens is that I have CoordinatorLayout as the parent layout (because its interaction between FAB and SnackBar) and ScrollView inside it containing RelativeLayout (Open to suggestions if you have a better way). And that for some reason makes problems when trying to add rules to layout params.
XML Code (Removed the radioButtons and CheckBox for easier viewing):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/saveAlarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:onClick="fabClicked"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_alarm_creator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.rome.locationalarm.AlarmCreator">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/alarmTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Alarm title" />

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alarmTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            tools:context="com.example.rome.locationalarm.MapsFragment" />

        <com.example.rome.locationalarm.CustomTimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/days"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Choose Location" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/map"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

JAVA Code (Only the important part):

```
 if(locationCheckBox.isChecked()){
                //If user wants location
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mapFragment.getId());
                //All of these don't work 
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0); // (left, top, right, bottom)
                //All of these are tries to center the radioGroup
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                layout.removeView(radioGroup);
                layout.addView(radioGroup, layoutParams);
                //layout.updateViewLayout(radioGroup, layoutParams); doesn't work as well.
```

Thank you for taking your time trying to help, have a nice year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do this to get the LayoutParams

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: try calling `requestLayout()` after making changes.  also you should use `getLayoutParams()` as @Tulsi suggests, and adjust instead of add/remove view.  also try just making that view `GONE` and change visibility instead.  also, `CENTER_IN_PARENT` overrides any other layout rules.  In any event it's the `requestLayout()` that triggers the view to adjust its children (in any `View`).

Comment: Thank you both guys! It works! and @escape-llc what does requestLayout() do?

Comment: that is a "signal" to the `View` that its layout is invalid, and on the next layout pass, it should re-calculate its children's positions.  the UI thread is in control of when this happens (i.e. it has a message pump); all of the `requestXXX` methods work the same way, by posting a message to the UI thread for execution "later".  this is also why it is unwise to manipulate the `View` hierarchy from within a `View`'s callback.